# How to convert the SVG g element transform translate value to pixel

Tags: jquery, svg

As title.
but i use translate was attribute not css. So how can i convert the translate value to pixel.
Here's the HTML code:

```
<g transform="translate(95,-8)">...</g>
```

Update Reason:
why i need to convert to pixel?
Because i need my web after loading, need css do some animation the animation need to follow the element coordinate. But the `div` translate need unit so i need to convert group translate to some specific unit, or it anyway can count that element width/height when web was loading success.

here's the element more information:

```
 <g transform="translate(95,-8)">
<pattern class="sNodes" id="image2" width="100%" height="100%" style="display: block;"><image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="images/1-01.png" id="node_id112" width="20px" height="20px"></image></pattern><circle r="10" class="sNodes" id="node_id112" onclick="NodesDownInlv3(112)" fill="url(#image2)" indicator="5-a-04-S03" original-title="" style="display: block;"></circle></g>
```

update more code:

```
<svg class="enable" id="svg1" width="100%" height="100%">
<g transform="translate(-10,-11)">
<g transform="translate(817,379)"><pattern class="sNodes" id="image2" width="100%" height="100%" style="display: block;"><image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="images/1-01.png" id="node_id112" width="20px" height="20px"></image></pattern><circle r="10" class="sNodes" id="node_id112" onclick="NodesDownInlv3(112)" fill="url(#image2)" indicator="5-a-04-S03" style="display: block;" original-title=""></circle></g>
</g>
</svg>

<div id="doSomeInfo"></div> //when web was loading success this will show some information, the information will follow the svg's group
```

thanks for help.

Comment: There's not enough information in the question, give me some more details please.

Comment: The numbers are in pixel units. Just add px.

Comment: @RobertLongson i have try it before. but the result are offset too much.

Comment: In that case you need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). It yields the position of the element relative to the top left corner of the viewport. So in case your structure is like that:

```
<div class="container">
    <svg>
        <g transform="…">
        …
        </g>
    </svg>
    <div id="someid">…</div>
</div>
```

You can subtract the `.containers` bounding Rect from the groups bounding Rect to get the relative offset from the group to the container.

Comment: It's work.
I use getBoundingClientRect() get six value, then i use top and left divided by 2 to get the value.But why need to divided by 2?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to offer you a guide, i might edit the answer if u are able to give out some more details.

You should firstly calculate your SVG's length and pass it back to your SVG element.

```
// access element you want to measure
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('yourtag')[i]; //you can use getElementById or class as well in her
el.getComputedTextLength(); // returns a pixel
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all why you need to convert it to pixel?

Simple Text:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <text x="20" y="40">Example SVG text 1</text>
</svg>
```

If your concern is only with font-size and styling try this

```
 <text x="20" y="40"
      style="fill: #000000; stroke: none; font-size: 48px;">
    Fill only
</text>
<text x="20" y="100"
      style="fill: none; stroke: #000000;  font-size: 48px;">
    Stroke only
</text>
<text x="20" y="150"
      style="fill: #999999; stroke: #000000;  font-size: 48px;">
    Fill and stroke
</text>
```

Are you looking for something else?